# Play sound in app

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio

Here is how I play a sound in my app

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"/sound.wav"];

    SystemSoundID soundID;
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

The code above works well in simulator, but not on device. Can you recommend me a simple
 way to play sound ?  I know about AVAudioPlayer, but I'm looking for something simpler. Like the code above.

Comment: AVAudioPlayer is simpler than this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I do it and it works fine both on Simulator and real Device

```
SystemSoundID sounds[10];
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"applause" ofType:@"mp3"];
CFURLRef soundURL = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &sounds[0]);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sounds[0]);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I get undeclared identifier "sounds". What &sounds[0] is ?

Comment: i am trying same code to play wav file, it plays on simulator but not on device....the issue is i have added buttons , clicking on which some text gets added to textfield.now i also want to play tones when button is clicked....but somehow file cannot be played...however the same code works for another view cntroller but not in my view controller